# VBA form vlookup type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, forms, textbox, vlookup

im trying to use the vlookup in a form to look for a value of a textbox in a table, and putting the result in a 2nd textbox. Simplified code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim carbon As Variant
    carbon = TextBox1.Value
Dim ih As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("initial hardness")
    ih = Application.VLookup(carbon, Worksheets("initial hardness").Range("A4:B64"), 2, False)
    TextBox2.Value = ih
End With

End Sub
```

table sample:

```
0,19  44,0
0,20  44,0
0,21  45,0
0,22  45,0
0,23  46,0
```

When I type 0,22 in a tb1, i get the Run-time error '-2147352571 (800200005)': Could not set the value property. The form seems to be working, when i change the fomrat in the first column to 0.22, and type 0.22 in a textbox, but its not what im looking for.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "With" block in your code is note necessary. So you can erase it..

Regarding your problem, it is not 100 % clear what you have changed. Because, the problems might be different, you could either have regional settings which use comma "," or dot "." for decimals separation or you could have problem with cells format (text or number format)

I would suggest to avoid using VLOOKUP in the code and try to use different approach for the problem.

If you still want to use VLOOKUP, "Application.VLookup" would not work in all Excel versions. I'd suggest to use "Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup" if you are going to use it on different computers.

Comment: i actually tried using application.worksheetfunction.vlookup, and i was getting error 1004 no matter what i did. Thats why i decided to use WITH, because it was the only thing that worked on my test form with simpler data, but with a real form i got the problem i described above.